# Parameter without default value in a Modelica model

Tags: modelica

### Context: Modelica 3.6 "Undefined modification" feature

In the release announcement of the Modelica language version 3.6 (see [Modelica Association Newsletter 2023-01](https://newsletter.modelica.org/2023-01/index#modelica-language-3-6-being-released)), there is a new syntax **Undefined modification**:

> Undefined modification - this allows making a parameter undefined, e.g., to **force users of the model to explicitly set it**. https://specification.modelica.org/master/inheritance-modification-and-redeclaration.html#removing-modifiers-break

However, the new syntax, if I understand it correctly, is only to remove the parameter value set the superclass when *inheriting* a model (with the `extends` keyword).

### Question

Now seeing this new syntax it just occurred to me that *I don't know how to specify that a model parameter shouldn't have a default value* in general (i.e. force the user of the model to specify its value).

For example, here is a short model where the value of `param` is not set:

```
model ParameterDefaultValue "A model with one parameter which shouldn't have a default value"
  parameter Real param "parameter which shouldn't have a default value";
equation

end ParameterDefaultValue;
```

Even if the value is not specified, this model *does* simulate, using a default value of 0.0 (in OpenModelica 1.20), albeit with a Translation warning: *[ParameterDefaultValue: 2:3-2:73]: Parameter param has no value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true), using available start value (start=0.0) as default value.*

More specifically, I wonder if it's possible for the simulation to *fail* rather than emit a warning. In a sense, it means that the model ParameterDefaultValue wouldn't be directly simulable, only after having been *extended* or simply *composed* is a larger model:

```
model UpperModel
  ParameterDefaultValue parameterDefaultValue(param = 1);
equation

end UpperModel;
```

### Relation to partial models

I see that my question resembles the use case of the `partial` keyword (abstract classes in other object oriented languages), *except that* `partial` is:

- for underspecified models (not enough equations), not the lack of parameter value
- the "partialness" is resolved by extending the model, whereas, as illustrated above, the lack of value can be provided at instantiation (whereas instantiating partial models is forbidden)

### Default values in other languages

Also, comparing to an imperative programming languages like Python, the default values of parameters in a function is an optional feature, not a default:

```py
def f(a, b=1):
    return a+b

f(2) # OK → returns 3
f() # fails with TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

Comment: Your model `ParameterDefaultValue` does not simulate in Dymola, returning the error `The following parameter doesn't have any value: param`. So it seems to be implemented differently depending on the used tool...

Comment: good to know @MarkusA. I wonder if the Modelica language spec says something on that front.

Comment: Based on comments and answers, I've brought the question to OpenModelica's discussions on Github (https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/discussions/10385) and an issue was raised (OM shouldn't accept models with parameters without value nor start value)

Comment: For the reference, link to the OpenModelica issue "Parameters without explicit start attribute modifiers should cause compilation to fail" https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/10386 (opened March 2023)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that OpenModelica version may be relying on another item that was changed in Modelica 3.6 (due to https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/pull/3226 ).

Specifically the messages says it uses the available start-value 0.0, and that seems to refer to the earlier definition of Real that did have a start-value of 0.0 https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#real-type

Technically the start-value should only be used as default if there was a modifier, but that was a bit unclear and the Pull Request removed the default 0.0 and clarified the use. (There might be additional changes related to this.)

Added:
Basically for parameters we can think of three cases:

1. Nothing, `parameter Real p;`
2. Start-default, `parameter Real p(start=1);`
3. Value, `parameter Real p=1;`

The idea is that later ones are "better", but before 3.6 the specification only specified that 2 should give a warning, but didn't really specify anything for 1. I believe that so many relied on the check in Dymola that no-one actually checked whether it was specified.

Note that case 2 was added in 3.3, and updated in https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2136

Comment: Thank for the explanation and precise references. Only thing unclear to me is *"I believe that so many relied on the check in Dymola that no-one actually checked whether it was specified."*. What is the behavior of Dymola?

Comment: Dymola generates an error for parameters without any default, and warning if it has start=...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Modelica Specification model ParameterDefaultValue is invalid. Since version 1.23.0 also OpenModelica will reject it. See https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/10386